# How to Use HQL to Select Rows with All Items in Given List

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two tables:

```
public class User  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // ... other fields and Getter / Setter methods
}

public class Group{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "group_user", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
    private List<User> users;

    // ... other fields and Getter / Setter methods
}
```

I want to select groups which all given users are in.

For example, now I have 3 groups:

1. User IDs: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
2. User IDs: 2, 4, 5, 7
3. User IDs: 5, 9

I want to select the groups which **User 5**, and **User 7** are in. (The result should be **group 1** and **2**)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Group g join g.users u where u.id in (:ids) ").setParameter("ids", ids); // ids is a list containing the user IDs
List<Group> groups = query.list();
```

Comment: I tried, but in the example, it will also select **Group 3** (I only want Group 1 & 2).